# Установка tensorflow в виртуально окружение

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, virtualenv, .env

Установил модули tensorflow и keras в свое виртуальное окружение. В проекте импортировал эти модули, но при запуске проекта получаю следующую ошибку:

```
    TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.
If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.
If you cannot immediately regenerate your protos, some other possible workarounds are:
 1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
 2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).
```

В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: Следовали вариантам решения ошибки из самой ошибки?

Comment: @r3b0rn Честно говоря я понимаю что нужно сделать в первом пункте, но не могли бы Вы пожалуйста подсказать как это сделать? И не понятно что от меня хотят во втором пункте

Comment: pip install protobuf==3.20.x